# Moderator actions in activity tab

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, moderators

Should the activity tab in the profiles of moderators list moderator actions too? For example, opening, closing, deleting, and undeleting. This information is already available from within the posts themselves, so it makes sense to tie it in with the rest of the moderator's activity.

Note, I'm not suggesting that *all* moderator actions be listed. Only those which are already publicly communicated.

Comment: /* thanks for the clean-up, mmyers */

Comment: why isn't it a feature request?

Comment: It's more of a feature-extension than a request, no?

Comment: @Jon, if you don't mind, I'll tag it `[feature-request]`.

Comment: If you want it to have the .00001% chance of getting implemented, I think it should be tagged as a request

Comment: @voyager: I don't mind at all if you guys feel it's appropriate.

Comment: i'd like this. sometimes i cast a close vote without leaving a comment. especially for close as duplicate, since the post i said it was a duplicate of is already listed without requiring me to leave a comment. in those cases i might want to check back later in the day to see what happened to that question, but i have no way of finding it again.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

Only thing to take into account if implemented for *all* users would be to extend the length of the list, or allow to paginate one or two pages back, as the activity tab would grow much faster were this to be implemented.

Comment: looking for a little free rep?

Comment: @Downvoter: just getting ahead of you to provide this answer ;)

Comment: why are you stealing my job?

Comment: @Downvoter: now I'm on the first page of Meta. *Oh God!*

Comment: There are no benefits... none at all... no t-shirt, nada

Comment: @Dow :( I'll go cry on that corner if no one minds.

Answer (score 3):

To be a little bit more broad, this information should be in *all* activity pages. If I can open and close, why isn't that reflected in my activity?

Comment: True, but our votes aren't binding. I'd still like to see a summary for *me personally*, but I don't care so much about seeing everyone else's history.

Comment: @mmyers: a compromise to this would be to log open/close actions in the activity log *only when a question is actually opened/closed*. This would then match the behavior on the revision history for questions themselves (voter names logged when question state changes).

Comment: @Shog9: I'd settle for that. But I'd still like to see my own votes even (and perhaps especially) if they don't result in actually closing or deleting the question.