# How can communication of moderator actions be improved?

Tags: discussion, flags

Currently there is very little feedback to users for the actions of moderators.

If you flag content, there is no notification that the flag has been considered, no way to determine the outcome of the review and not even a clear indication that you have already used a flag in some situations.

As someone whose content is flagged, there is no indication that it has happened, and no indication of the outcome. If your post is deleted there is no indication of why it was deleted or appeal option.

There does seem to be a page that exists somewhere with more details, but there are no obvious links to it. Certainly no inbox/email notifications.

This extremely poor communication leads to misunderstandings. For example, a moderator deletes a comment. The author is not notified in any way, they simply return to the site some time later and find what they wrote is not there. Did they forget to hit post? Was it just a network error? Was it a moderator, and if so for what reason and how do they appeal? Further posts risk enraging moderators who perceive it as trying to subvert their efforts.

How can communication be improved?

Note: not a dupe of [Moderator actions in activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43704/moderator-actions-in-activity-tab), that only related to moderator actions that are publicly reported.

Comment: these links should work for you https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/370230 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/23064 for EE.SE outcome of your reviews: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/23064/%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BC?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @rene I'm getting page not found from your link

Comment: @PolyGeo because it's a *private* link, visible to the user only. Rene is just constructing them.

Comment: Those links are not on the page anywhere. How are they discoverable?

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157344/interpreting-my-flagging-history-sidebar

Comment: @rene Thanks. Can we help newer users by making that easier to find, and having notifications perhaps? I also note that there is no option to appeal or engage with the moderator there, you can only re-flag for someone else to look at which resets the conversation state and seems to cause the red mist to descend.

Comment: Also that page doesn't seem to show the outcome of your own posts that have been flagged by other people.

Comment: The usage is explained in the [flag privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), if users don't read that, why would they read anything else. To contest a flag outcome you can either go to Meta, find a chatroom where a mod is lurking or use a custom flag to explain why you think the mod made the wrong decision. I personally never bother if stuff gets declined.

Comment: As for seeing moderation actions on your own content: you only know if you keep your eye on your deleted answers/ questions. For deleted comments you'll never get feedback unless you choose to be rude all over the place, a mod might leave a comment for you. Comments are considered low-grade and its removal should be frictionless and not lead to end less debates about how valuable they are.

Comment: @rene that's my point, due to lack of feedback it's easy for misunderstandings to happen and the moderators interpret them as "rude". Lack of communication is the main cause of poor moderation.

Comment: @rene as for why expecting users to read documentation is a bad idea, that's probably a question for UX... But suffice to say, any web site that relies on users reading large amounts of explanatory text instead of simply providing a notification is probably in trouble.

Comment: Given the userbase of Stack Overflow and SE as a whole I still have to see the *trouble* to become significant.

Comment: @rene okay, well... It's significant to me.

Comment: Related (posted by the same user): [Moderator communication is poor](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357825)

Answer (score 6):

TLDR: The tooling exists, but the need rarely does for feedback on flags. If something is flagged, its rarely critical enough to require mod contact.

---

As a moderator, I've always considered flags to be a one way street - the point of a flag is to get attention for a post of any sort, so that someone trusted can take a look and handle it appropriately.

There *are* mechanisms in place for a certain degree of broad feedback on flagging as a whole (badges/helpful flag counts for positive reinforcement and flag bans as negative reinforcement), but I don't think flags were ever intended to be a means of feedback to the *flagger*.

The *original intent* of flagging was to [replace having to email SE for content problems](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/11/raising-a-red-flag/). It scales reasonably well on most sites and we're able to handle most sites because we're handling the *problems* rather than trying to explain why we're doing something. In the few situations where I've had to give *feedback*, it took a fair bit longer than just processing the flags, but you're always free to take it to meta.

So, specifically

> Currently there is very little feedback to users for the actions of moderators.

This is somewhat by design. Feedback won't scale *that well* I suspect. I've handled maybe 400 or 500 flags so far this month, and feedback for all of them would be noisy. If there's a direct benefit most of the time, sure. If feedback is *required* we can use mod messages (for private things), superpings - for somewhat public feedback via chat or the flag feedback option (which exists).

We *rarely* need to supply feedback on flags though, and its rarely something impacting long term usage.

> If you flag content, there is no notification that the flag has been considered, no way to determine the outcome of the review and not even a clear indication that you have already used a flag in some situations.

Practically speaking, flags are designed to bring attention to a post. In *many* situations a moderator does not see the flags and they're handled by the community anyway. On the whole, its *unlikely* that you would need to review our handling of a specific flag, nor is it likely to affect the use of the site *unless* there is a pattern of bad flags.

> As someone whose content is flagged, there is no indication that it has happened, and no indication of the outcome. If your post is deleted there is no indication of why it was deleted or appeal option.

Well, yeah. You can *always* see your own deleted questions and answers. In *many* cases we do delete comments, but its worth remembering, comments are transient by design. In a *few* cases we do end up sending mod messages or have a quiet word, but on the whole the need for this is uncommon.

I suppose we *could* let people see their own deleted comments, but I don't know how useful that would be. I can think of less than 3-4 times when someone asked me about deleted comments

> This extremely poor communication leads to misunderstandings. For example, a moderator deletes a comment. The author is not notified in any way, they simply return to the site some time later and find what they wrote is not there

Oddly enough, this rarely happens in my experience. *Usually* I don't instanuke comments and very often comments of value tend to be converted into a chat room. Usually if someone keeps reposting a comment, there's ... other reasons to be unhappy. In these cases we'll try to feed back.

> Further posts risk enraging moderators who perceive it as trying to subvert their efforts.

As a mod? At most I roll my eyes, take a deep breath, and leave a comment, mod message, or superping. But I can't even remember the last time I needed to.

Comment: When I say "feedback" I mean at least notifying the person flagged. A mod deleted some comments I and another user made discussing something with no warning, no notice recently. Due to the confusion the conversation continued, so they deleted again and that time posted a short message explaining, which resolved the situation.

Comment: Your remaining calm is admirable, unfortunately in my experience not all moderators are capable of that level of restraint.

Comment: Which is why I said comments are transient for design. And not really meant for extended discussion. Its entirely plausible at some point this comment thread would be deleted, and... that's by design

Comment: which is even more reason to notify the participants. Things disappearing without a trace is not good UX.

Comment: @user329044 The moderation here is designed to de-escalate things. Telling someone that they were flagged escalates things and tends to make people overly concerned with the flag. Many times flags are invalid... what is the point of telling you about an invalid flag?

Comment: @Catija not notifying escalates things by causing confusion.

Comment: @user329044 How can you be confused if you don't even know you were flagged?

Comment: @Catija the comment vanishes. As I said already, there is no way to know if you accidentally didn't post it, if the site screwed up and didn't properly submit it etc. Sometimes you just plain forget you already made a similar comment.

Comment: Another issue is that if you are getting a lot of comments deleted there is no way to know without carefully surveying your previous contributions, until one day an angry mod bans you out of the blue.

Comment: @user329044 "angry mod", you never voted on a election here, did you? These folks are the most cool headed and helpful you'll find around.

Comment: @brasofilo again, that's not my experience. I found the site staff to be calm and to communicate clearly. Some mods are fine, others... Not. I think better communication would help everyone.